# How can a comment be added to a case from a customer using Salesforce's SOAP API?

Tags: soap-api, case, case-comment

I'm attempting to use Salesforce's SOAP API to add a comment to a case from a customer, but I'm getting a `Created By ID: id value of incorrect type` error when I set the `CreatedById` to the customer's contact record ID.

```
[errors] => Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CreatedById
                )
            [message] => Created By ID: id value of incorrect type: 00355000004bUsWAAU
            [statusCode] => FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
        )
)
```

I can add a comment to a case if I leave the `CreatedById` field blank, but the field defaults to the Salesforce account I'm accessing the API with. Does anyone know how I attribute the comment to a contact record instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CreatedById` field only supports `User` values. You cannot specify a `Contact` value under any circumstances. Note that you can only set `CreatedById` if you first [Enable Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enable-Create-Audit-Fields&language=en_US).